# PHP Anonymous object - integer properties

Tags: php

I've created an anonymous object, using PDO FETCH_OBJ from my DB. I can access most properties fine using:

```
$myObject->name;  
$myObject->age;
```

etc.

But I have one field in my DB that starts with an integer. '`130x90_url`

When trying to access `$myObject->130x90_url;` I then get :

```
syntax error, unexpected '130' (T_LNUMBER), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'
```

I can't see anything in the manual about this, but would of thought others would of come across this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo $myObject->{'130x90_url'};
```

That works on `SimpleXMLElement` instances, and *should* work on instances of `stdClass`.
More details can, probably, be found [on the variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) doc page.

Comment: Perfect. I tried $myObject->{130x90_url} before asking, but was missing the ' ' . I'll accept answer when I can. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might also be able to assign the property name to a variable and use that as a property.

```
$property = "130x90_url";
$value = $myObject->$property;
```