# Using `/` as an array index in PHP, then casting to object

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an array that is defined as such:

```
$bar = array(
   '/' => 'foo'
);
```

I can convert it to a class (using `$baz = (object) $bar`), and I don't get any errors. `$baz` contains the following: (via `var_dump`)

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["/"]=>
  string(3) "foo"
}
```

However, I can't seem to find a way to access the `/` property of `$baz`. I thought I could use `$baz -> /;`, but obviously there are syntax issues with that statement.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Anonymous object - integer properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236687/php-anonymous-object-integer-properties)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this syntax

```
$baz->{'/'};
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

> Curly braces may also be used, to clearly delimit the property name.
>   They are most useful when accessing values within a property that
>   contains an array, when the property name is made of mulitple parts,
>   or when the property name contains characters that are not otherwise
>   valid